# How to deal with Excel data efficiently

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have firm level data on various variables but large set of data is missing. So I want to reduce the size of my data set by dropping the firms which have very less number of observations. I do not want to do it manually. Is there any efficient way to deal with this problem in Excel?

Comment: Your question does specify Excel. I can't resist the comment that this would be about two lines of code in Stata, and I have every hope that it would be as easy in other statistical software. In other words: Excel is not a very good machine for data management.

Answer (score 3):

Create a copy of your workbook so that you can modify it

1. Create a new sheet in you new workbook.
2. Get a unique list of company names and
   put this into the new sheet. You can do this using the filter
   command without duplicates.
3. Now, use the countif() function to count how many times each company appears. Figure out what your cut-off will be based on this, meaning decide how many times a company needs to have an entry for it to be included.
4. Suppose you only want to keep companies with 10 or more observations. In your original sheet with all of the observations create a new variable called COUNT in a column and use the VLOOKUP function where you want to look up the company name in the new sheet and import the count of how many times that company appeared. This should give you a column in which for each company you have a value in the COUNT column corresponding to how many times that company appeared (the value should be the same for all observations of that company).
5. Sort your original sheet by the COUNT variable in decreasing order. This means companies with the most observations will be on top.
6. Delete all companies with less than ten observations.

To summarize: Figure out how many times each company appears. Sort the observations by that value. Drop the companies that have too few observations.

I don't know if this is really a statistics question so much as an Excel question.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something similar to @Deathkill14's answer, but I would build steps 1-5 using a Pivot Table.  In the PivotTable Field List pane, I would drag the Company Name to the Row Labels and drag it again to the Values region to get a Count by name.

Then I would click on any of the Company Name cells in the Pivot Table, and from the Data ribbon click Sort, then choose Descending by Count of Company Name.

If you are trying to manage big data sets in Excel you should look into Power Pivot aka Excel Data Model.  This compresses data for performance and supports table relationships and formulas.